# Roslyn Check Type of an Attribute

Tags: c#, linq, roslyn

I'm trying to figure out there proper way to compare attribute data in Roslyn.

```
static bool ResolveAttributes(IMethodSymbol methodSymbol)
{
    var attributes = methodSymbol.GetAttributes();

    return null == attributes.FirstOrDefault(attr => isIDEMessageAttribute(attr, typeof(MyAttributeType)));
}

static bool IsIDEMessageAttribute(AttributeData attribute, Type desiredAttributeType)
{
    //How can I check if the attribute is the type of desired?
}
```

How can I check if the attribute is the type of desired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AttributeData.AttributeClass` gives you the Roslyn symbol for the attribute. But you've got a CLR runtime Type you are trying to compare against.  You can either just compare the type names, etc, to see if they are the probably the same type, or get a Roslyn type symbol for `MyAttributeType`, which is more correct. This is typically done via

```
var desiredSymbol = sematicModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(MyAttributeType).FullName)
```