# Determining if a field is serializable with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm finding very little good documentation on Roslyn so forgive me if I missed something and this should be obvious.
I'm parsing some code and my aim is to pull out every serializable field from a class.

What I have so far is this. First I parse the code file

```
            SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(programText);
            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                                                             .AddReferences(MetadataReference
                                                                                .CreateFromFile(typeof(object)
                                                                                                .Assembly
                                                                                                .Location))
                                                             .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

            CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
```

Next, I get all the fields from each class

```
        foreach (MemberDeclarationSyntax member in root.Members)
        {
            if (member is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclarationSyntax)
            {

                foreach (MemberDeclarationSyntax rootGameMember in classDeclarationSyntax.Members)
                {
                    if (IsFieldSerializable(rootGameMember))
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

aaaaand now I'm stuck. What I want to do with this field are a few things based on the Unity 3D rules for serialization

- See if the type is public
- See if the attribute [SerializeField] is applied
- See if the type is int, float, string, double etc
- See if the type, if its a class has the [Serializable] attribute

I think that's it. At the moment I'm trying to figure out the type of the field and getting lost in a rabbit warren of options of which none seem to give me what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is get the symbol representing your field, which you can do by using the `SemanticModel` class. I think this would help explain how you get the semantic model based on your example:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis

TLDR: use `compilation.GetSemanticModel()`

This questions answers how to do this better than my original answer, so please look here:

[How to get a Roslyn FieldSymbol from a FieldDeclarationSyntax node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848576/how-to-get-a-roslyn-fieldsymbol-from-a-fielddeclarationsyntax-node)

Now you have the semantic information about the field, let's look at each problem one at a time.

#### 1) See if the type is public

This should be pretty simple, as the `IFieldSymbol` interface has a `DeclaredAccessibility` property which will tell you what you need to know!

```cs
if(fieldSymbol.DeclaredAccessibility != Accessibility.Public)
{
    // not interested in no-public members
}
```

#### 2) See if the attribute `[SerializeField]` is applied

Use the `GetAttributes()` method of the `IFieldSymbol` interface. Then you can just query the attribute's `AttributeClass` like any other `INamedTypeSymbol`.

```cs
var attributes = fieldSymbol.GetAttributes();
if(!attributes.Any(attribute => attribute.AttributeClass.Name == "SerializeField"))
{
    // only interested in fields with the SerializeField attribute
}
```

#### 3) See if the type is `int`, `float`, `string`, `double` etc

Luckily, `Type` is a property of the `IFieldSymbol` interface too, so we can just check that property of our field symbol. You can reference the `Name` property of the resulting `ITypeSymbol`, if you only care about simple types.

```cs
var fieldTypes = new List<string> { "int", "float", "string", "double" };

if(!fieldTypes.Contains(fieldSymbol.Type.Name))
{
    // only interested in certain types
}
```

(You may want to double check the type name strings in the debugger)

#### 4) See if the type, if its a class has the `[Serializable]` attribute

From this I'm guessing you mean that the class has the `[Serializable]` attribute. For this you can use the same approach as 2, but you need the class symbol, so this will have to be done outside of your field checking function.

```cs
var classSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(classDeclarationSyntax).Symbol;
// remember to null check this
var attributes = classSymbol.GetAttributes();
if(attributes.Any(attribute => attribute.AttributeClass.Name == "Serializable"))
{
   // class is serializable
}
```

**EDIT**:
This answer may also help you if you think checking attributes by name is a bit hacky!

[Roslyn Check Type of an Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381039/roslyn-check-type-of-an-attribute)

**IFieldSymbol:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.ifieldsymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet

**INamedTypeSymbol**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.inamedtypesymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet

And I totally agree btw, good Roslyn documentation seems to be incredibly rare.

Comment: Thanks so much for that detailed answer. That's a big help. Now I'm struggling getting the field symbol. Thats going to be one of two things I'm guessing. The type is `public List<MyClass>` so either the SemanticModel doesn't know about List or it doesn't know about MyClass. My codebase is parsed from numerous files so I guess I need to include them all in `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText` rather than just the first file. If the problem is List then I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: You'll need the ```TypeArguments``` from the the list's symbol. Also ```GetDeclaredSymbol``` from the semantic model could be worth using.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.inamedtypesymbol.typearguments?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_INamedTypeSymbol_TypeArguments)